# graphicImage not displayed after switching to Glassfish 4.1.1

Tags: glassfish, jsf-2.2, glassfish-4.1

Prior to switching to GF 4.1.1 I was using GF 4. The images were displaying but not anymore. images in the "images" folder are showing though. Not in the subfolders.

```
 <h:graphicImage styleClass="flag" library="images/flags"
name="US.png"/>
```

> csbasement\WebContent\resources\images\flags\US.png

Comment: Food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11988415

Comment: @BalusC Thanks. It's a bit hardcore I'll need to reread it. But it works with name="images/flags/US.png" and the library omitted.